# Linux: How can I delete all files whose file name is more than X characters in length?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-management

I want to delete all files in the current directory and sub directories whose file name is more than a particular length.

Is there an easy way of doing this from bash?

Comment: Asking questions to yourself, Kitsos?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae yes, and this is both [OK and encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/203101) on the SE sites. I am also interested in other ways of doing this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already provided a `find` command that is safe for oddly named files:

```
find -regextype posix-egrep -type f -regex '.*[^/]{5}' -delete
```

This regex matches five trailing characters that do not contain a slash (i.e. the filename is longer than five chars).

The Bash loop you provided will generally work, but it probably does not scale with thousands of files and may break with special filenames.

An alternative that is similar in efficiency, but may provide more flexibility (replace `rm` by `-n1 echo` to print all files):

```
find -type f -print0 | grep -Ez '[^/]{5}$' | xargs -0 rm
```

The `-print0`, `-z` and `-0` options ensure that each file name is terminated with a NUL byte. This ensures that special characters do not split filenames (newlines break the Bash command you provided). Although this `grep command` still fails with a name such as `path/abc\ndef` (where `\n` is a newline), it won't be split up into `path/abc` and `def`.

As you will rarely find files with `\n` in their name, I leave the implementation for that case as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this so I don't accept mine but the `find -delete` actually is the safest way of dealing with weird names (including newlines). The bash loop in my answer will only break if the names contain `\`, it can deal with everything else AFAIK, including spaces and new lines. Granted that `xargs` with the correct arguments for parallelization will probably be faster but I tend to go for the safe one when I don't know what files I'm dealing with.

Comment: @Kitsos I did not say *faster*, but *flexible*. If you need to post-process the file list, then external programs may be easier than using a find regex. Your bash answer will fail with newlines. Consider a file name names `foo\nbar` (with an embedded newline). Then the first iteration will read `foo` and the second one `bar`. If you had files named `foo` or `bar`, then you will lose them, even if the length of `foo\nbar` is longer than five (seven). Another useful property `find` is that the `-delete` options removes empty directories too.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find` to locate all files in the current directory and subdirectories, then measure the length of the file name using bash and delete accordingly:

```
$ find . -type f | while IFS= read -r file; do 
    ## find will return the full path, strip the
    ## path from the file name. 
    name=$(basename "$file"); 
    ## Check the name'slength and delete if > 5
    [ "${#name}" -gt 5 ] && rm "$file"; 
  done
```

Alternatively, you can do everything from `find` by using `-regex` and `-delete`. For example, to delete file name of more than 5 characters (excluding the path):

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*[^/]{5}' -delete
```

Comment: {5,} to be precise. It's <i>more than a particular length</i>. Not to be pedantic but to avoid misunderstandings on the use of quantifiers.

Comment: @Peter as far as I know, the `{N,X}` format is exclusive to PCREs which `find` does not support. In the `posix-egrep` format, `{5}` means "five or more", try it.

Comment: For the `rm` command, change `$name` to `$file` for this to work properly.  Was just thinking about implementing in Perl, and it is such a straight conversion.

Comment: @Kitsos that's why I mentioned it. The regular expression without the additional ',' in the quantifier didn't work for me, though I thought the approach is quiet elegant, so I modified it.

Comment: LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: openSUSE project
Description:    openSUSE 12.3 (x86_64)
Release:        12.3
Codename:       Dartmouth

Comment: @Peter weird, both `{n}` and `{n,} work but they have the same effect, so does `{n,m}`. I'm using `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`.

Comment: @Kitsos - Add the `-delete` switch to the second example, and it will do as advertised. :-) _I'm also curious why the RE cannot be simplified to `[^/]{5}$`?_ Without it, it doesn't work. egrep doesn't require it, as in `find / -type f | egrep '[^/]{5}$'`; further, .* evaluation in regular expressions is expensive because it's greedy, and I therefore try to avoid using .* if at all possible to speed execution.  On BSDish xNIX, like OSX, use the -E switch to find to achieve the same as on your example - just because I was playing around with this on OSX and just now tried it on linux.

Comment: @Kitsos yes, it is. I am using find (GNU findutils) 4.5.10, and though Open Suse is known to be somewhat specific , I would not expect different behavior at the system core utilities.

Comment: Forking is expensive, this command does not scale up with thousands of file (yes, I have encountered that). The `name=$(basename "$file")` can be replace with `name=${file##*/}` (Bash prefix substitution with nothing).

Comment: @Kitsos `for file in **/*; do` is probably preferable to the `find` loop if using bash 4+ (`shopt -s globstar` to enable globstar)

Comment: @Kitsos "In the `posix-egrep` format, `{5}` means "five or more", try it." I believe you are wrong. It does mean "exactly five" but as the expression stands right now, `.*` munches any previous characters, ie any file name longer than 5 characters just so happens to also end with 5 non-slashes and will also match. To prove that `{5}` matches exactly 5 characters, try the expression `.*/[^/]{5}`.